# React: update state on prop change

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

Let's say all three component configurations below are valid:

```
<Arc radius="200"/>
<Arc radius="90% - 20"/>
<Arc radius={this.calcRadiusFn}/>
```

First will use the absolute value 200 for the arc radius.

Second will set the radius to 90% of the default radius (which is derived from the size of the arc's container) minus 20 pixels.

Third will use the provided `calcRadiusFn` function to calculate a radius (the function is given the default radius and uses some logic to return some derived value).

In all three cases I would actually like to transform the received `radius` prop to a function:

```
1) (x) => 200
2) (x) => x * 0.9 - 20
3) (x) => Math.sqrt(x) + 42
```

So that in the `render` method I could just do:

```
const radius = this.radiusFn(defaultValue);
// or
const radius = this.state.radiusFn(defaultValue);
```

I know there is `getDerivedStateFromProps`, and old ways have been deprecated this summer: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

But `getDerivedStateFromProps` doesn't seem like the right place to do this. You *can* use it to do this, but you are basically creating your own ad-hoc solution for each prop you want to transform, as well as remembering the value of the previous prop, etc. Is there a systemic/idiomatic way to process props before they are used?

Comment: the way i do it is i try to make minimum `props` transforms in the child component. i always pass `usable` forms to the child components..

Comment: Why not wrap `Arc` in a higher order component that manipulates the data accordingly prior to passing to actual `Arc`?

Comment: @hannadrehman @AlexanderStaroselsky I feel like this is the responsibility of the `Arc` component to make sense of the input, not mine to spoon-feed it. But even if I create a higher order component, won't it have the same issue?

Comment: @Vitaly. i dont know the implementation of `Arc` component. but by looking at it and the props name,  your `Arc` should only take radius and draw the arc. its a simple presentational component i guess. i dont think it should do any transforms to the props.

Comment: @hannadrehman This isn't an actual component, just an example to  show the problem. The idea is to update a state whenever a prop changes and then use that state to render the component. Sometimes you can use props directly, sometimes you can't, I want this to be completely transparent to the user of the component.

Comment: @Vitaly well in that case you have `getDerivedStateFromProps` combined with `componentDidUpadte`. or directly in `render`. i personally don't like either, but i dont think there is any other option to do it.